# Telerik DatePicker on MVC4 app, Date Format Validation issue

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I have this model:

```
public partial class Cita
{
            public DateTime dia1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime? dia2 { get; set; }
}
```

have this on my view:

```
@model HCB.Azure.CP.UI.Areas.User.Controllers.AgendaController.Cita
@Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("dia2")
@Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("dayx")
```

have this on my web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="es-CR" culture="es-ES"  />
```

As you can see, there are 2 DatePickers, dia2 is bounded to the model, dayX is not, now the problem is when in dia2 choose or type a date in format dd/MM/yyyy like 15/04/2013 it becomes red but if choose 04/15/2013 (MM/dd/yyyy) it clean red validation error and becomes valid.

I don't have this problem with dayX wich is not bounded to the model, and also, this error only happens on some devices like a samsung tablet or iphone chrome browser, it works perfect on my developer machine (windows 7)...

I don't know what is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

The default format for a DateTime via the Telerik DatePicker UI control I believe is MM/dd/yyyy. You need to tell the date picker a different format via the format method.

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("dia2").Format("{0: dd MM yyyy}")
```

You could also try setting the format of the Date in the controller before passing the model to the view